# What are the ways to search for several alternate characters without creating a capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have a task to search for words that start with either `a` or `b`, for example `all` or `bll` words. I know I can use grouping and `or` operator like this:

```
(a|b)ll
```

But this creates a capturing group. Are there any other options?

Comment: Use a non-capturing group?

Comment: Better question: What aspect of capture groups are you trying to avoid?  Their purpose is for cases like the one you described*

Answer (score 1):

How about using square brackets instead of parens like: `[ab]ll` ?